# I'm having problem looping through Upload file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I do this code:

```
uploaded_file_info = ol.upload_file(c:\video\file.mp4)
print(uploaded_file_info)
```

It works just fine

But when I try to loop from a CSV file
it gives the error below:

code:

```
with open('ListTest.1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
        name = (line[0])
        VidPath = (line[4])
        print(name)
        print(VidPath)
        uploaded_file_info = ol.upload_file(VidPath)
        print(uploaded_file_info)
```

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PrintingTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    uploaded_file_info = ol.upload_file(VidPath)
  File "C:\Users\resta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openload\openload.py", line 258, in upload_file
    files={'upload_file': open(file_path, 'rb')}).json()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ' c:\video\file.mp4'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ' c:\video\file.mp4' => 'c:\video\file.mp4'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a space at the beginning of the string in your error messsage. See if a .strip() fixes it by changing:

```
uploaded_file_info = ol.upload_file(VidPath)
```

to

```
uploaded_file_info = ol.upload_file(VidPath.strip())
```

You might want to fix it a different way, but this will tell you right away if the space is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the space at the front of the path. `' c:\video\file.mp4'`. your csvreader is spliting on `','` (comma) not `', '` (comma space). Pass correct delimiter to `reader` function or use string function `strip` on line[4]